# Помогите указать ключи

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Дана модель:

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

        public IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }

        public IList<ProfileUpdate> ProfileUpdates { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Заметка")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; } // активен ли аккаунт
    }

    public class Street
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Адрес 1")]
        public string Street1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Адрес 2")]
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Phone
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Телефон")]
        public long Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("E-mail")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProfileUpdate
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Street Street { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Почтовый индекс")]
        public int PostalCode { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Город")]
        public string Town { get; set; }
    }
```

Пытаюсь создать контроллер MVC5 с представлениями, использующими EF для работы с этой моделью, но пишет ошибку, что Adresses: EntityType 'Adresses' has no key defined. Такое же пишет и для Email, Phone, Emails, Phones, EntitySet Adresses. Что мне изменить?

dbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может у вас что-то неожиданное пропиписано в настройках контекста, скиньте код DbContext

Comment: стандартный шаблон проекта из коробки, ничего не менял, кроме как создал модели и пытаюсь создать к ним контроллер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключом должно быть что-то уникальное для всех записей такого типа в таблице. `type` например - не подходящее для этого поле. Заведите для всех по аналогии с `Customer`:

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

В итоге так:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Имя")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ProfileUpdate> ProfileUpdates { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Заметка")]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; } // активен ли аккаунт
}

public class Street
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Адрес 1")]
    public string Street1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Адрес 2")]
    public string Street2 { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Телефон")]
    public long Value { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("E-mail")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ProfileUpdate
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdateDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }

    public Street Street { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Почтовый индекс")]
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Город")]
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: не помогло, выдает все ту же ошибку.

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе - посмотрим чего вы там сделали

Comment: А кто [key] то за вас расставлять будет?

Comment: а разницы нет, я проставил изначально, не помогло, убрал. Сейчас перепроверил, вернул, но ошибка не ушла.

Comment: Выглядит все нормально, уж не знаю чего у вас там не заводится

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Имя")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

        public IList<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

        public IList<Email> Emails { get; set; }

        public IList<ProfileUpdate> ProfileUpdates { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Заметка")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; } // активен ли аккаунт
    }
```